# Keyboard Hide/Show issue in iPhone 5c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, uikeyboard

From past few days I am facing a weird `keyboard` issue that is only happening in `iPhone 5c` only.

I am using `objective-C` for Development in `Xcode-6.4`

My environment target is `ios7`.

Here is How I am handeling `keyboard Notification`.

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

To `Deregister Notification` I am writing this piece of code.To be sure I use `-resignFirstResponder` for every textField.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[self hideKeyBoard];
[self.view endEditing:YES];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)hideKeyBoard{

[kAgeTextField resignFirstResponder];
[kSchoolTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And In submit button I have checked some condition and then I am showing an `AlertView`.

```
- (IBAction)submitClicked:(id)sender
{
if(validated)
 {    
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self hideKeyBoard];
    [self.view resignFirstResponder]; 

    [self makeApiCall];
 }
}
```

Now when I get Success/Failure Response from server I am doing this.This is the block which runs after getting response from server:

```
-(void)SuccessfulWithServerInfo:(id)responseInfo
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [appDelegate hideProgressViewFromView:self.view];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Thanks for coming" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


});

}
```

**Problem** When I get alertBox and press ok. Then keyboard opens up and closes automatically. This is happening i iPhone 5C only. I checked it in 4s,5s,6 and 6Plus. All are working fine.

If anyone knows about it please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some Research I found this answer In stackOverflow.

Their is some change in the behaviour of AlertView in ios7 and in ios8.

I use this code to solve my issue:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
```

For details answer please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129278/keyboard-pops-up-after-uialertview-is-dismissed-on-ios-8-3-for-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying alert at same time you are also doing popToRootViewController. May be this will cause problem.

1. Display alert.
2. Handle alert view method.
3. Write  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]  in alert view's method.

   ```
   [UIAlertView showWithTitle:@"" message:@"Thanks for coming" cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] alertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault tapBlock:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *text)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
        }
   }];
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: no change,,,My all textfields are in table view...will table view rate problem

Comment: That tableview is on same viewcontroller where alertview is displaying?